# Anonymous access gets authenticated

Tags: access, anonymous-authentication

I have a strange problem with anonymous access in my site-collection in SharePoint 2013(in all sites collection were visual upgraded to 2013 or site-collections that were created in farm 2013 from the beginning )

I grant to anonymous user to see Entire web site.

I disabled this feature in site collection :`Limited-access user permission lockdown mode`

I created custom SharePoint list in my site and set all permission for anonymous user (check all permission can get)

When calling this list by anonymous user creates items in list  normally and without any problem but in editing item:

An anonymous user can edit items that were created by authenticated user but he can't edit items that were created by anonymous user. I mean in last situation the window for authenticating shows.

The above problem does not exist in sites-collections that are in Visual SharePoint template 2010, I mean there weren't upgraded visually.

I deep in my problem and I want to say more details.

I thought the anonymous user steps in every page corrupts it.

Assume this are the items in the list:

1. item_createdbyInternaluser_1
2. item_createdbyInternaluser_2
3. item_createdbyExternaluser_1
4. item_createdbyExternaluser_2

When you call this list by an anonymous user you can edit 1 and 2, but you can't edit 3 and 4.(the authentication window appears) You assume to edit 1.

The items changes to below list:

1. item_createdbyInternaluser_1_editedbyAnonymoususer
2. item_createdbyInternaluser_2
3. item_createdbyExternaluser_1
4. item_createdbyExternaluser_2

After that, you can't edit 1,3 and 4 but you can edit 2. Why?